# Minimizing an $l_1$ objective function - first derivative is 0

Tags: derivatives, optimization

The context of my question is minimizing the following function:

$$C(w) = \frac{1}{2}(y - w)^2 + \lambda|w|$$

I am told that when $w = 0$, we have that $$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin} \argmin_w C(w) = 0$$

but how do we know this if when $w = 0$, $C(w) = \frac{1}{2}y^2 \implies C'(w) = 0$ (first derivative test gives us "no information")?

Comment: If $w = 0$, how can you optimize wrt $w$?

Comment: That is essentially my question - this is regarding a hw question I am being asked

Comment: Are you sure it's not "if y = 0"?

Comment: yes - positive. the other two cases were for w>0, w<0